# Alternatives to "skating on thin ice"

Tags: idioms, synonyms

The idiom *skating on thin ice* to express that a person is performing an action that has a great risk is commonplace. What are some good alternatives, both common and uncommon or possibly regional?

Comment: Am i missing something, or does that not belong here, please?

Why would you not ask your own search engine, then consider the results, then come here with specific queries about what didn't seem to work for you?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin You may be missing the fact that this is a 9-year-old question, which was marginally acceptable at the time but is clearly lacking according to current standards.

Comment: Oops! thanks, Hallion… I did miss the date…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To greater or lesser degrees of risk and stupidity:

- Walking on the edge

  Asking for trouble

  putting yourself at risk

  loading up the footgun

  skating down the edge of a razorblade

  pissing on the third rail

  walking/driving on the railroad tracks

  trying to shoot the moon

  jumping the Grand Canyon on a skateboard

  walking a tightrope

  operating without a net

  playing with fire

  licking a frozen flagpole

  letting the bull into the china shop

Comment: To me, _trying to shoot the moon_ and _jumping the Grand Canyon_ are more about infeasibility/impossibility/futility than risk.

Comment: I think of _licking a frozen flagpole_ as an activity that is more stupid than risky.

Comment: Yes, it certainly does fall on the "stupid" side of risky.  :-)

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman! Answer awarded for the most comprehensive list.

Comment: I think you're out on a limb with that list.

Answer (score 1):

"On thin ice" can also refer to a situation out of your control. The proverbial skater didn't necessarily choose the thin ice but is nonetheless in a risky place. Alternatives to this connotation (branching a bit further away from consciously taking a risk):

- Out of the frying pan, into the fire
- Doomed
- Writing on the wall

Comment: Ah yes, it *could* mean less of an intentional risk and more of a circumstantial risk. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Hanging by a Thread
- Playing Russian Roulette
- Kissing Charlie Sheen

Comment: Ahhh the Russian Roulette metaphor. I should use that one more... even if it is a bit grisly. =)

Comment: Kissing Charlie Sheen? That's... new. =)

Answer (score 1):

How about "pushing your luck"?

Answer (score 1):

*Playing a dangerous game* is another alternative with a similar meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I have some more

Swimming in the deep end of a ocean

Jumping a volcano

Driving a vehicle without stopping

Comment: Oceans have deep _ends_?

Answer (score 0):

"Walking on eggshells" has a similar, but not identical, connotation.

Comment: Almost opposite connotation: `skating on thin ice` means taking a reckless risk; `walking on eggshells` means behaving very cautiously because you believe the situation to be inherently risky.